# Insert Fixed Values into MYSQL using html <button> - AJAX PHP (No Refreshing)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

so i'm trying to insert data into my MYSQL db. When a user clicks on a button I would like to send the unique ID number of that button to my MSQL database without refreshing the page.

I've seen lots of AJAX examples using form data, but none to do with fixed values using only html  without forms.

Does anyone have any examples I can use? really stuck on this one!

Parts of my code so far:

HTML

```
<button id="vid1" class="btn jubi-touch-btn jubi-masterplan active" onclick="">Jubilee<br>Masterplan</button>

<button id="vid2" class="btn jubi-touch-btn jubi-schools" onclick="">Schools &<br>Childcare</button>

<button id="vid3" class="btn jubi-touch-btn jubi-shopping" onclick="">Local<br>Shopping</button>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        var uniqueId = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'assets/php/process.php',                        
            type: 'POST',                                  
            data: {
                uniqueId :uniqueId
            },
            success: function(response){

            }
        });
    });
});
```

CONNECT PHP

```
<?php
   $dbhost = "XXX";
   $dbuser = "XXX";
   $dbpass = "XXX";
   $dbname = "TouchMap";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

PROCESS PHP

```
<?php
$uniqueId = $_REQUEST['uniqueId'];
?>
```

Comment: please show us what you have done

Comment: I haven't done anything on the AJAX side of things and have no idea where to start. I have a simple HTML document with buttons and unique ID's and a connect.php which connects me to my DB and thats it. Need some AJAX code that takes the button click and sends that ID number to my database, any ideas?

Comment: You should show us the code you have so far, even if it's only a form submit, you can then AJAXify it afterwards but you need to be at the point where you can insert something to the database or you're missing a step an d we can't help you.

Comment: Sorry, new to the site. I've posted some of my code above.

Comment: There are 1000's of tutorials out there on the web, do a few. SO is nto a tutorial site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        var uniqueId = $(this).attr('id');
        // I am assuming that there are lots of button and having unique numbers as there id

        $.ajax({
            url: 'process.php',                        
            type: 'POST',                                  
            data: {
                uniqueId :uniqueId
            },
            success: function(response){
                // do your stuff here
            }
        });
    });
});
```

process.php:

```
<?php
$uniqueId = $_REQUEST['uniqueId'];
// code to insert it in DB
?>
```

**Note:** Include the jquery library in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mayank but I cant get it to work... does the proocess.php need a sql statement to insert the data?

Comment: Yes, **// code to insert it in DB** here you have to put your sql query to insert the code in your database

Comment: Okay cool. something like this?
$sql = "INSERT INTO mydbname (VIDEOID) VALUES ('uniqueId')";

Comment: Yes, fire this query using mysqli_query();

Comment: Sounds great, don't forget to accept the answer if it helps you :D